# Docker Login to gcr.io in Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'm trying to log in to Google's Container Registry on Windows 10 by using a [JSON Key file](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file). I have this working without issues on my Mac so the keyfile is definitely working.

First off I had issues getting the docker login function to accept the contents of the JSON key file. I've tried running the "*/set /p PASS...*" command in CMD and I've tried something along the lines of this in Powershell:

> docker login -u _json_key -p "$(Get-Content keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io

These all result in either an error or this:

> "docker login" requires at most 1 argument.

Since I couldn't get this to work, I ran:

> docker login -u _json_key https://gcr.io

And then just removed all breaks from the JSON file manually, copied it to clipboard and pasted it when prompted for my password.

That results in:

> Login Succeeded

Problem solved! Right?

Well apparently not. I was still unable to pull my images and when I ran *docker info* the only registry listed was "https://index.docker.io/v1/".

I've tried starting Powershell as admin, and restarted and reset docker but nothing seems to help.

Anyone got any clue what is going on? How do I debug this?

I'm running Docker version 17.12.0 (stable)

Comment: Can you share what error message you getting while executing docker pull command? It seems that your project service account (which is linked to docker) does not have access to container registry which securely store your docker images. You may want to check if your project service account has required container registry access or not? Please refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file) for further details.

Comment: I'm using the same key file on my Mac where I'm able to do the pull command without issues. I'm just wondering why *docker login* reports succeeded but I can't see gcr.io in as a registry in *docker info*.
I tried the way suggested in the Cloud documentation - It's the first link in my post :)

Comment: Apparently one of the localized hostnames (such as us, eu, or asia) has to be added with URL gcr.io for docker [push or pull](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling).
Can you confirm what information in docker info make you suspect that you are not logged in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution that works for both Windows (in PowerShell) and bash. The secret is to use the ["provide a password using stdin"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#provide-a-password-using-stdin).

```
cat gcr_registry-ro.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
Login Succeeded
```

Help text and versions:

```
PS C:\Users\andy> docker login --help

Usage:  docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]

Log in to a Docker registry

Options:
  -p, --password string   Password
      --password-stdin    Take the password from stdin
  -u, --username string   Username
PS C:\Users\andy> docker -v
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
PS C:\Users\andy>
```

Comment: ```unknown flag: --password-stdin```

~|⇒ docker -v                                                                                                          
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be

Comment: @ArjunNayak Update your version of docker. If you installed via an OS package maintainer (such as Ubuntu, or Linux Mint) chances are you'll be stuck on an old version. Docker has steps to install the latest version on their website.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell:

```bsh
(Get-Content keyfile.json) | docker login  -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now by using the trick I did with removing all line breaks in the key, copying it and then pasting it when I'm prompted for my password, instead of trying to pass it into the *-p* parameter.
Turns out I had to change the url to *eu.gcr.io* instead of just *gcr.io*.

I wrote some feedback on the GCR documentation page - Hopefully they'll fix it and maybe even add the correct way to do it in Powershell.

Only thing I'm still wondering is why I can't see that I'm logged into GCR in *docker info*.